# How to dynamically increment validation cells on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Let's suppose I have a cell A1 on a google spreadsheet "Sheet1" with a validation rule that is "Sheet2!1:1". Now if I click on the bottom right corner and expand the cell to A2, A2, ..., An, all will have the same validation rule.

However, I wanted cell A2 to have the rule "Sheet2!2:2", the cell A3 the rule ""Sheet2!3:3" and so on.

Is there any way to achieve this without manually edit the validation rule for each cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use a formula like this one, where it dynamically references the row:

```
=indirect("'Sheet2'!"&row()&":"&row())
```